# How to share a Neo4j HA cluster with multiple Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, database-cluster

I have a cluster of 4 Neo4j instance (v.1.9.3) with following initial_host:

```
ha.initial_hosts=192.168.1.10:5001,192.168.1.10:5002,192.168.1.10:5003,192.168.1.10:5004
```

I am using this cluster for one of my spring app (using Spring-data-neo4j) for which I have kept following configuration in my applicationContext file:

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase"
    destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton"> 
    <constructor-arg name="storeDir" index="0" value="E:/Neo4J Enterprise Edition/db1/data/graph.db" />
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <map>
            <entry key="ha.server_id" value="5" />
            <entry key="ha.pull_interval" value="10" />
            <entry key="ha.server" value="192.168.1.10:6005" />
            <entry key="ha.initial_hosts" value="192.168.1.10:5001,192.168.1.10:5002,192.168.1.10:5003,192.168.1.10:5004" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean><neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />
```

Cluster is running properly, with proper sync / replication of data between instances.

Now is it possible to share cluster or run another application on the same cluster ?
To achieve this I wrote another configuration for second app as follow:

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase"
        destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton"> 
        <constructor-arg name="storeDir" index="1" value="E:/db_5/graph.db" />
        <constructor-arg index="2">
            <map>
                <entry key="ha.server_id" value="6" />
                <entry key="ha.pull_interval" value="10" />
                <entry key="ha.server" value="192.168.1.10:6006" />
                <entry key="ha.initial_hosts" value="192.168.1.10:5001,192.168.1.10:5002,192.168.1.10:5003,192.168.1.10:5004" />
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />
```

but it always end up with exception. Following are the few lines of it:

```
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterClient@9bad4f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin@c47498' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterClient.start(ClusterClient.java:421)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: i was denied entry
    at org.neo4j.cluster.protocol.cluster.ClusterState$2.handle(ClusterState.java:199)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.protocol.cluster.ClusterState$2.handle(ClusterState.java:121)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.statemachine.StateMachine.handle(StateMachine.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.StateMachines$1.run(StateMachines.java:135)
    ... 3 more
```

Is there any thing wrong with second configuration ? I visited this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/LWr_RcsPUS4). and tried with changing `ha.server_id` and `ha.server` entry key and running the project on two different machine of the same domain, but no help.

Can any one please point me out what I am doing wrong here ? Thanks

Comment: I asked and this is an issue that seems to be fixed in Neo4j 1.9.6 which should be out soon.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHunger could you suggest some alternative of it ? is neo4j 1.8.x will be suitable for this ? I haven't tried with older version yet.